# Reading a file though a link

Tags: r, csv, shortcut

I have a directory where I keep all my .csv files. I have created a shortcut for this directory. Now, I want to read those csv's through this shortcut.

```
read.csv("<shortcut to directory>/input.csv");
```

Above command doesn't work. Complains about "Unable to create the connection"

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you create a shortcut for the directory?

Comment: Typically `read.csv` and other `R` functions which open connections do not "understand" Windows .lnk link files.  If your directory has a virtual drive letter, see the documentation for `?base:connections` .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using Windows, note that the shortcuts you create within Explorer are not part of the filesystem: they're just an Explorer-specific trick. When you double-click on the shortcut, Explorer knows to open the location it points to, but other applications won't know what to do with them.

Windows *does* have symbolic links a la Unix, but by default you have to create them from the command prompt, with the `mklink` command. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) for more info.